# Using exception handling

Tags: exception, integer, user-input, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create an exception block that reads an error message and shuts down the program gracefully if my user inputs anything other than a number. How can I achieve this?

```py
x=int(input("Choose a number:"))

try:
    x==int()

except:
    print("Invalid input.")

    sys.exit()

y=int(input("Choose a number:"))

try:
    y>=0 or y<=0

except:
    print("Invalid input. Please try again.")

    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the `try` block lets you test a block of code for errors.
The `except` block lets you handle the error.

In `except` block you can use `ValueError` as you are trying to convert the input to an integer, so if the input value is an `integer`, the code in the `try` block will be executed. otherwise the code in the `excpet` block will be executed.

You can use the while loop to exit the program only when you want by changing the value of the `start` variable to `False`.

```py
start = True

while start: 
    try:
        x=int(input("Choose a number for x :"))
        y=int(input("Choose a number for y :"))

        # if x > y:
        #     print("x is greater than y")
        # elif x == y:
        #     print("x equal to y")
        # else:
        #     print("x is less than y")

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number")
        start =  False
```

---

Learn more about exceptions:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp
2. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Learn more about while loop:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp